# Fazer uma ou mais buscas no banco com php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com dificuldades de fazer uma busca no meu banco de dados com o código em PHP em que eu possa pesquisar um "item" porém com mais do que uma palavra chave.

Por exemplo: Tenho um banco em que abrigo informações principais como ip's, nome de usuários etc. Consegui fazer um código de busca mas somente se eu buscar com o IP desejado, como faria para pesquisar também por nome e outras informações.

Segue meu código:

```
<?php
    $buscar = $_POST['pesquisar'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM principal WHERE ip LIKE '%".$buscar."%' ");
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if($row > 0){
        while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $ip = $linha['ip'];
            $nome = $linha['nome'];
            $setor = $linha['setor'];
            $idpc = $linha['idpc'];
            $tag = $linha['tag'];
            $modelo = $linha['modelo'];
            $tipo = $linha['tipo'];
            $so = $linha['so'];
            $observacao = $linha['observacao'];
            echo "<strong>IP: </strong>".@$ip;
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "<strong>NOME: </strong>".@$nome;
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "<strong>SETOR: </strong>".@$setor;
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "<strong>IDPC: </strong>".@$idpc;
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "<strong>TAG: </strong>".@$tag;
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "<strong>MODELO: </strong>".@$modelo;
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "<strong>TIPO: </strong>".@$tipo;
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "<strong>SO: </strong>".@$so;
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "<strong>OBSERVAÇÃO: </strong>".@$observacao;
            echo "<br /><br />";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Não há nenhum usuário registrado!";
    }
?>
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Na variável $buscar, o usuário está digitando somente pelo IP ou possui mais parâmetros?

Comment: Você quer recuperar do banco registros de acordo com o seu `$buscar` e este pode ser um IP, Nome ou outras informações ? Isso ? Se for isso, tentou usar um `OR` no seu select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode concatenar vários `LIKE` ou quaisquer outras verificações com o [AND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) ou outros operadores lógicos do mySQL.

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM principal WHERE ip LIKE '%".$buscar."%' AND nome LIKE 'nome' AND setor LIKE 'setor'
```

Nesse caso ele estaria retornando todas as linhas que satisfaçam as 3 condições propostas.

No caso de verificar se alguma das colunas satisfaz a palavra digitada pelo usuário, você pode utilizar o [OR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM principal WHERE ip LIKE '%".$buscar."%' OR nome LIKE 'nome' OR setor LIKE 'setor'
```

Na query a cima ele estaria retornando todas as linhas que satisfaçam pelo menos uma das condições propostas.

Dê uma olhada nos operadores lógicos do mySQL que você pode estar utilizando: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: Vinicius se o que ele diz na pergunta faz sentindo , usando o exemplo de "um item" por várias palavras chaves , o ideal seria concatenar likes com o operador "OR".
Ao entender da pergunta ele tem um único filtro de pesquisa onde , OU ele digitaria o nome ou o ip e assim por diante.

Comment: @Felipe então, posso ter interpretado mal, mas pelo o que eu entendi ele gostaria de puxar linhas que satisfaçam mais de uma situação, levei em consideração a frase dele " também por nome e outras informações.", posso estar errado.

Comment: @Felipe acho que agora ficou mais completo!

Comment: Deu certo aqui! não fui muito claro na pergunta mas era essa ideia que entenderam. Muito obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi direto você terá somente a variável `$buscar` como filtro, podendo ser um IP, Nome ou outras informações.

Neste caso, você pode usar um `OR` na sua consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM principal 
    WHERE ip LIKE '%".$buscar."%' 
    OR nome LIKE '%".$buscar."%' 
    OR setor LIKE '%".$buscar."%'
    //OR .. OUTROS FILTROS ..
```

Lembrando que isto pode trazer outras informações que não condiz com a sua busca devido a utilização de vários `OR`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo e era justamente o que eu estava pensando em fazer!